# How to replace substrings in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe, where I want to replace some words to others, based on another dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dist = pd.DataFrame([["21","apple"],["25","balana"],["30","lemon"]],columns=["idx","item"])
a = pd.DataFrame(["apple - banana"],columns=["pf"])
a['pf'] = a['pf'].replace(dist["item"], dist["idx"], regex=True)
print(a)
```

How can I do that? (this does not work in its current form)

Comment: Do you want `a['pf']` to be `'21 - 25'`

Comment: Yes, '21 - 25' is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dist = pd.DataFrame([["21","apple"],["25","balana"],["30","lemon"]],columns= ["idx","item"])
a = pd.DataFrame(["apple - banana"],columns=["pf"])
b = dict(zip(dist["idx"], dist["item"]))

def replace_items(token):
    for key, value in b.items():
        token = token.replace(value, key)
    return token

a["pf"] = a["pf"].apply(replace_items)
```

Please be aware that the `banana` in your `dist` dataframe is `balana`. Not sure if this is intended...

Answer (score 0):

Converting the translation table to dictionary seems to solve the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
dist = pd.DataFrame([["apple","21"],["banana","25"],["lemon","30"]],columns=["item","idx"])
dist = dist.set_index('item')['idx'].to_dict()
a = pd.DataFrame(["apple - banana"],columns=["pf"])
a['pf'] = a['pf'].replace(dist, regex=True)
print(a)
```